# Why does getAppWidgetInfo return null sometimes?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

When updating my app widget I need to check the provider class name.
`appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(widgetId).provider.className`

But sometimes I face the exception `Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.content.ComponentName android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo.provider' on a null object reference`

And I don't know why. Documentation of `getAppWidgetInfo` says:

> If the appWidgetId has not been bound to a provider yet, or you don't
> have access to that appWidgetId, null is returned.

I guess my case is "the appWidgetId has not been bound to a provider", but how to catch the moment when a widget is bound already? Or maybe the problem is something else?

Comment: Can you provide more of a [mcve], showing where `appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(widgetId).provider.className` appears, along with the full stack trace?

Comment: @CommonsWare that's not easy because the issue is floating and nobody guarantees reproducing. Maybe has sense the fact that I call  `getAppWidgetInfo` in a WorkManager task which starts immediately in `onUpdate`.

Comment: Finally I rewrote my code and got rid of `getAppWidgetInfo` call but the question is still open.

Comment: "Maybe has sense the fact that I call getAppWidgetInfo in a WorkManager task which starts immediately in onUpdate" -- that may be [a bigger problem](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115575872#comment4). "that's not easy because the issue is floating and nobody guarantees reproducing" -- that does not prevent you from showing where `appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(widgetId).provider.className` appears, along with the full stack trace.